Spring Security login success but still 403
I'm trying to setup a basic login endpoint for a RESTful API. I just want to be able to send via POST the user credentials, validate them and setup a cookie, nothing fancy with the session yet. No matter what I do, I get 403 even if my Authentication Filter seems to be capturing the Loging Request successfully and passing it to my AuthenticationManager, which correctly sets the authentication to authenticated.
Here's my SecurityConfig:
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO: Enable CORS and CSRF protection
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .addFilter(new JsonAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                )
                .build();
    }

My AuthenticationManager:
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return new ProviderManager(authProvider);
    }


And my JsonAuthenticationFilter:
@Component
public class JsonAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    public JsonAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        System.out.println("Attempting to authenticate");
        if (!"POST".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
            String jsonBody = stringBuilder.toString();
            LoginRequest loginRequest = objectMapper.readValue(jsonBody, LoginRequest.class);
            authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.username(), loginRequest.password());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Failed to parse authentication request body", e);
        }
        System.out.println(authRequest);
        setDetails(request, authRequest);
        Authentication authenticate = this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
        System.out.println(authenticate);
        return authenticate;
    }

}

If I try a POST to localhost/login with Postman, I get the following output:
Attempting to authenticate
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=admin, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=false, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]
Loading user by username: admin
Found: edata.test.my_overengineered_app.authentication.credentials.Credentials@629ebc06
Found Bindings: [LIST_USER, CREATE_USER, MANAGE_USER_ACCESS]
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=edata.test.my_overengineered_app.authentication.Identity@692c1bad, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=A52D919E3DFCE2B45843488B2B1C3AB7], Granted Authorities=[LIST_USER, MANAGE_USER_ACCESS, CREATE_USER]]


Based on the output, my Json filter is triggering correctly, my UserDetailsService as well, and the AuthenticationManager successfully identifies the user. But somehow I still get a 403 response, and trying other protected routes with the cookie I received results in a 403 as well, as if the authentication didn't take place. I have read multiple posts, the Spring Security reference for both Authentication and Authorization and have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated :(

From Spring Security 6 on the SecurityContextRepository must be set explicitly, as described in the Spring Security Migration Guide. You should try the following:
@Component
public class JsonAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @PostConstruct
    private void setup() {
        super.setSecurityContextRepository(
                new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                        new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
                        new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()));
    }

    public JsonAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        ....
    }
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // TODO: Enable CORS and CSRF protection
    return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .addFilter(new JsonAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager))
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement((session) -> session
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
            )
            .securityContext(securityContext -> securityContext
                    .securityContextRepository(
                            new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                                    new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
                                    new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
                            )))
            .build();
}

Also I'd recommend you to read this question here: How to properly set SecurityContextRepository for a custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in Spring Security 6?

Omg you're an angel! I had to manually call the setup on the Json filter constructor for it to work though, even with the @PostConstruct annotation, do you know why?
Btw, did you find out if it's possible to use just one instance of the DelegatingSecurityContextRepository?

Well, in our production setup it's not necessary to call super other than via PostConstruct, sorry that I'm not able to clarify this issue by now. Regarding your second question, no, we haven't dug into it further, although we haven't encountered any problems while using the same respoitory for both cases. Anyhow, we do use two different repositories since they have two different use cases - just to be safe ;)

I cannot thank you enough, you don't know just how desperate I was. I made the SecurityContextRepository into a Bean and injected it to my JsonFilter and the PostConstruct worked! Btw, I'm still very new into Spring, trying to soak myself of any knowlegde I can. Would it be possible that you shared how you use 2 different SecurityContextRepositories in production? I'm very curious

Similar to your approach, just 2 beans injected and that's it. But as unconditional pointed out in his answer here you can omit providing a custom repository since Spring will then create one for this purpose itself. I'd recommend you to trial end error as much as possible, just do it and don't listen to anybody sayin: this isn't necessary. You won't learn anything that way. Do it, learn it, and finally decide whether to go with Spring's autoconfig or your own custom config. Whenever autoconfig is possible go for that, but first learn the why behind.

Thank you for your comments. I've decided for a Bean definition, I think that, even with no other component using it, it could be useful to expose it in case other components may need it. It feels kind of YAGNI, but I find it cohesive with the rest of my solution, let's see where it takes me!
